# Is there a way to change page indicator dots color

Tags: iphone, colors, uipagecontrol

I am newbie to iphone programming, I am trying to develop an app which uses page control. My view's background color is white and page controllers default one is also white, which makes page control invisible on my view so I have changed the back ground color of page control to make is visible. Now, the view appears patched and bad. Is there a way to change just the dots color for page control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate question. BTW, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol, given solution is one of the best in the world. Personally i used it so many times.

Comment: you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648988/code-to-give-different-color-for-each-pagination-dots-in-ios/26649447#26649447

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We customized the UIPageControl to use a custom image for the page indicator, I have listed the guts of the class below...

GrayPageControl.h

```
@interface GrayPageControl : UIPageControl
{
    UIImage* activeImage;
    UIImage* inactiveImage;
}
```

GrayPageControl.m

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    activeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"active_page_image.png"] retain];
    inactiveImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive_page_image.png"] retain];

    return self;
}

-(void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == self.currentPage) dot.image = activeImage;
        else dot.image = inactiveImage;
    }
}

-(void) setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    [self updateDots];
}
```

Then in the View Controller we just use it like a normal UIPageControl

```
IBOutlet GrayPageControl* PageIndicator;
```

**Edit:**

In the view controller that has the GrayPageControl I have an IBAction that is linked to the GrayPageControl.ValueChanged event.

```
-(IBAction) pageChanged:(id)sender
{
    int page = PageIndicator.currentPage;

    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    CGRect frame = ImagesScroller.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [ImagesScroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I also added an override to layoutSubviews that just called updateDots - it removed a slight flicker when the control was first added :)

Comment: I'm just looking for your solution and can not get it work. I try to connect *PageIndicator to UIPageControl element in Interface Builder with no luck. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: It works now. I just set the PageControl class to UIPageControl in Interface Builder.
But now I want to make "dots" (images) larger. I have done this in updateDots() method:
dot.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
When I fire up app it is ok. But on scrolling it shows me only one. Is there a solution?

Comment: I solved the problem:
dot.frame = CGRectMake(dot.frame.origin.x, dot.frame.origin.y, 20., 20.);

Thanks man, your code is simple, yet awesome!

Comment: The code is more simple and awesome.I got this working.Now my only problem is i want to reduce the space between one dot and the other dot.How can i achieve this?

Comment: edit your code according to memory management. Also the new custom pageControl is blinking.

Comment: You should initialize initWithCoder and initWithFrame with some common initialization.

Comment: -(void) setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page isn't called when I clicked the button.

Comment: Just to let you know, this crashes on iOS7 (compiling with Xcode 5) as UIPageControl subviews are not UIImageViews any more.

Comment: not working in ios 7. Give exception "Unrecoganised selector" because [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] returns UIView instead of UIImageview and image is not property of UIView. pLease check and provide some solution to my [Question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024167/subviews-of-custom-uipageviewcontrol-return-uiview-in-ios7-but-uiimageview-in-io]

Answer (score 18):

The application crashes in iOS7. I have a Solution for iOS 7:

Reason for Crash:

in iOS 7 `[self.subViews objectAtIndex: i]` returns `UIView` Instead of `UIImageView` and `setImage` is not the property of `UIView` and the app crashes. I solve my problem using this following code.

Check Whether the subview is `UIView`(for iOS7) or `UIImageView`(for iOS6 or earlier). And If it is `UIView` I am going to add `UIImageView` as subview on that view and voila its working and not crash..!!

```
-(void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView * dot = [self imageViewForSubview:  [self.subviews objectAtIndex: i]];
        if (i == self.currentPage) dot.image = activeImage;
        else dot.image = inactiveImage;
    }
}
 - (UIImageView *) imageViewForSubview: (UIView *) view
{
    UIImageView * dot = nil;
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UIView class]])
    {
        for (UIView* subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                dot = (UIImageView *)subview;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dot == nil)
        {
            dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            [view addSubview:dot];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dot = (UIImageView *) view;
    }

    return dot;
}
```

Hope this solve ur issue too for iOS7. and If Anypone find the optimal solution for that please comment. :)

Happy coding

Comment: If you dont want the white rounded colors on background just add view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; in beginning of  imageViewForSubview method.

Answer (score 15):

JWD answer is the way to go. However, if all you want is to just change the color, why not do this:

**This technique will only work on iOS6.0 and higher!**

[image]

Select your UIPageControl go to attribute inspector. Tada.

Or alternatively you can play around with these 2 properties:

```
  pageIndicatorTintColor  property
  currentPageIndicatorTintColor  property
```

This is so simple. I read the question again to make sure I am not wrong. You really just want to change the color don't you? Then yes.

You're still stuck with that lawsy dots. Use JWD technique for the awesome dot pictures.

Comment: I don't want to boast. Though JWD answer is very good, mine is the only one actually answering the question :D

Comment: if i want to do the same in iOS 5 then what will i do ?

Comment: i follwed appcoda tutorial for building the uipageview controler in my app. I didn't find any controls that you mentioned above. is these controls still available in x code 6 ?  if there pleas help me with some details. Like to change the selected page's dot as blue and others to be back dots -thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

just one line of code fir your demand. The example set to black color.

```
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

[DDPageControl](https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl) is an excellent replacement. Check it out!

You can also view the archived blog post [here](http://ddeville.me/2011/01/ddpagecontrol-a-custom-uipagecontrol).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the page indicator tint color and the current page indicator tint color with the following code:

```
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to change color of dots or customize it you can make it as recommended by JWD, but in little bit another way:

```
#pragma mark - LifeCycle

- (void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    [self updateDots];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++) {
        UIView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == self.currentPage) {
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHEX(0x72E7DB);
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
        } else {
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHEX(0xFFFFFF);
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2 - 1;
            dot.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromHEX(0x72E7DB).CGColor;
            dot.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

As result you will get something like

[image]

Also macros:

```
#define UIColorFromHEX(hexValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: To do its work properly, you must disable User Interaction. Otherwise there is a glitch !

Answer (score 2):

The best and most siple way to do this is to add the following lines of code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate.m

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna have a look on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol) in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related answer for using a custom image (if you're flexible and can use an image rather than altering the colors directly).

[Customize dot with image of UIPageControl at index 0 of UIPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190147/customize-dot-with-image-of-uipagecontrol-at-index-0-of-uipagecontrol/40938446#40938446)