# UIPageControl: dots with rectangular format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I use native `UIPageControl` in my objective-c application and I want to have a rectangular dots instead of circular one. I searched about that and for a library providing this but I didn’t found anything.

I tried to do it like this but it has no effect:

```
-(void)updateDotsFormat {
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.pageControl.subviews count]; i++)
    {

        UIView* dot = [self.pageControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        UIView* dotView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        CGRect frame = dotView.frame;
        frame.size.width = 50;
        frame.size.height = 20;
        dotView.frame = frame;
        [dot addSubview:dotView];

    }
}
```

How can I set the dots format to rectangle?

Comment: It might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190147/customize-dot-with-image-of-uipagecontrol-at-index-0-of-uipagecontrol

Comment: @Harrathhichem you want to say that I can use a rectangle image and use it?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

> and I want to have a rectangular dots instead of circular one. I searched a that and for a library providing this but I didn’t found anything

Well, you would have to design your own view/control, since UIPageControl has no such ability. There are libraries for such a thing, but asking for one is not permitted on Stack Overflow; or you can write it yourself.

Comment: I didn't ask for a library. I ask for the way to do it

Comment: Well, it's a view containing a row of shapes (yours will be rectangles) that keeps a count and changes the color of the shapes depending on that count. It also permits a tap at the right or left to change the count, and emits a control event when that happens.