# UIPageControl images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a page control in my app.
**It has circle images to tell you what page you are on.**
How can I change the images from circle to something else?

Thanks.

Comment: you should've googled it before ! +1 Wain...

Comment: custom image for the page indicator you can find in post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color

Comment: I'm sure you are a beginner (no problem with that) but in the future, give google a chance to show you how to do what ever you want to do, if google doesn't want to tell you how to do it, maybe check the apple dev web site and check the properties/methods of your controls/classes that you are using, if these two steps didn't provide a solution post on SO a well documented/written question. Other than this, Wain's link is perfect for you ;)

Comment: All the solutions are at least on year old. It be nice to find something more recent!