# Change transparency of dots in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageViewController` with a transparent background and I'm wondering if I can make the non-selected page dots opaque. They're current translucent and I can see my background through them.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use custom images for dots. See [this thread for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but there's a `pageIndicatorTintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor`, both of which take a `UIColor` where you can probably set the alpha. Although the docs warn:

> No alpha is applied to this property for you. It is recommended (but not required) that the color you specify for this parameter contains some transparency–i.e. the alpha value should be less than 1.0.