# How to change page controller dot images?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I am having Page Controller, added on my scroll view. Page Controller is working FINE along with my Scroll View. But I need to implement Different images on Page Controller's Indicator(i.e. the dots that appears in page controller). That is different image for selected indicator, and different Image for not-selected indicator of Page Controller. Please Help. I searched a lot over internet. tried to find third party files, but they are about either the shape or color of the indicator. Please Help.

And PLease addd link of this page, in the answer, coz its not working with in my case :
[Is there a way to change page indicator dots color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set image of dots in page control. This below code is work in ios 6 and above.

```
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_inactive.png"]];

    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_active.png"]];
```