# Is it possible to add a custom image page indicator on a Page view Controller native indicator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to add a custom image page indicator on a Page view Controller native indicator?

If possible, help me how to do it ?

[this is the reference image not the actual one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I0uw.png)

Comment: you can change the color of indicator as per your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you normally want to change color of indicator then you can change directly color there is no need to change image by this way

```
let pageVC = UIPageControl()
pageVC.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
pageVC.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

But you want to change the image of `PageIndicator` then try this link:-

Answer with GrayPageControl:- [Is there a way to change page indicator dots color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color)

It is really good and reliable.I also have used this code.

You might have to do some more customization as

```
-(void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if (i == self.currentPage) {
            if(i==0) {
                dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activesearch.png"];
            } else {
                dot.image = activeImage;
            }        
        } else {
            if(i==0) {
                dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inactivesearch.png"];
            } else {
                dot.image = inactiveImage;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: UIImageView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
may i know what is this code used for ?

Comment: it is PageIndicator imageView

Comment: yes, i can know that .but what and why we use this ?
[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i]

Comment: if you are using GrayPageControl which inherit from UIPageControl then you can write above method updateDots and you can access PageIndicator imageView via  self.subviews

Comment: but the situation is, i created the pageController programatically

Comment: it dose not matter ,you can use it

Comment: you are welcome bro and one more thing if my answer is helpful for you then up vote it.

Comment: i have only 3 reputations

Comment: it's oky no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have page control ref then use

```
   let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([ViewController.self])
   pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
   pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```