# Tint UIPageControl dots in different colors - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I'm using a default UIPageControl and i have 2 tint colors - one for current age and one for the rest. 
I want the pages before the current pages, i.e. passed pages (in the screenshot attached - current page and previous ones should be tinted red, the following page gray), to be tinted with the same color as the current page, while the pages after it are tinted in a different color. 
pageIndicatorTintColor and currentpageIndicatorTintColor tint either on or all dots, not only some. 
Any advice how to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color  Might be helpful. Moreover you have to add extra coding in the code to get desired result.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol

Comment: I think it is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol

Comment: @ArpitJain as i wrote in my question - these properties help only for changing all the dots or the dot of the current page. They do not help for what i need.

Comment: If you have multi color dots, how would you distingush which page you are on ? There is a reason apple doesnt support multi color dots! You should implement a custom pag control using uiview!