# pagecontrol indicator custom image instead of Default

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

[How can i change the color of pagination dots of UIPageControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol/4073602#4073602)

In this link the sample code is given.But it shows 3 errors for me...

1'st ERROR:

Line:CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;

Error:requst for member 'bounds' in something not a structure or union

Method:-(void)drawRect:

2nd Err: same error with same line in touchesBegan method.

3rd Err:@protocol PageControlDelegate

@optional

- (void)pageControlPageDidChange:(PageControl *)pageControl;

@end

Error:Expected ')' before 'PageControl'  .These are the three errors occurs for me...Please help me out to solve this..

I want to change the pagecontrol indicator(dot) color...

Thanks & Regards,
Renuga

Answer (score 2):

first error is probably due to the fact that `self` does not refer to a view (a view controller maybe)

Second error is because PageControl is not yet defined by the time the parser come to your protocol definition.

Typical Class with delegate

```
@protocol MyProtocol;

@interface myClassWithDelegate
{
  id<MyProtocol> _delagate;
}

@end

@protocol MyProtocol
  -(void)MyClass:(MyClassWithDelegate*)c says(NSString*)message;
@end
```

Comment: Hi...now it not showing an error...but,page control indicator color is not yet changing...where should i add the color dot image and how can i set it as page control indicator...please Explain me as brief as possible...Thank You

Comment: For that you probably need to refer to the original post. I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who wrote the sample code you are using.

I see that VdesmedT has already helped you on the syntax issues you were having. So +1 for that!

As for customizing the dots: The class as provided does not support custom images for the dots. It just draws circles using Core Graphics. The color of the circles is configured using the properties `dotColorCurrentPage` and `dotColorOtherPage`.

The default colors are grey dots with a black dot for the current page (because that is what I needed when I wrote it).

Let's say you want a red dot instead of a black dot for the current page and green dots for the other pages. When you create your `PageControl` instance you simply assign the properties like this:

```
pageControl.dotColorCurrentPage = [UIColor redColor];
pageControl.dotColorOtherPage = [UIColor greenColor];
```

... assuming your instance variable is called `pageControl`. Or use any of the other convenience/initialization methods for creating a `UIColor` that you like.

Hope this helps.