# How to change the colour of the UIPageControl when used in ios 5 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5, uipagecontrol

I am using the following code in my application :-

In .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

and in .m file

```
pageControl.currentPage = counting;
```

counting is `NSInteger`. The application works fine but the `UIPageControl` is set to default white colour and I cant change the colour through attributes inspector
could any one help?...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In ios 6, you can just do:

```
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar as below.

[How can i change the color of pagination dots of UIPageControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol)

I think there is no property for page controller to change the dot color