# change color uipagecontroller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

[image]

how can i change color uipagecontroler like this ?

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [?];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [?];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [?];
pageControl.tintColor = [?];
```

i already try to change tint color whitecolor and background clearcolor but its not working, mabye i miss something?

thx for helping me

Comment: Check this category in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol).I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in applicationdidfinish Launch in App Delegate

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: its not working, btw i need to keep set pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];